# I need to fetch my pivot values from many to many relationship data

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm, pivot

I have done much research about this but I can't fetch the pivot table as I want.
I want to just fetch the measurement value from the pivot table-like structure you can see. Please check my all details first then you know what I want to show.

Model MeasurementPart.php

```
public function customers(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Customer::class, 'customer_measurements', 'measurementpart_id', 'customer_id')->withPivot('measurement');

}
```

Model Customer.php

```
public function measurementparts(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(MeasurementPart::class, 'customer_measurements', 'customer_id', 'measurementpart_id')->withPivot('measurement');

}
```

Model CustomerMeasurement.php

```
public function customers(){

    return $this->belongsToMany(Customer::class);
}

public function measurementparts(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(MeasurementPart::class);
}
```

Here is my controller CustomerMeasurementController.php

```
 public function editMeasurements(Request $request, $id){

        $customer = Customer::with("measurementparts")->find($id);

        $clothType = ClothType::all();
        return view('customerMeasurements.edit', compact('customer', 'clothType'));
}

public function updateMeasurements(Request $request, Customer $customer){


        $measurements = $request->input('measurement');
        $filteredmeasurements = array_filter($measurements, function($a){
            return $a !== null;
        });

        $measurement_id = $request->input('measurement_id');

        $result = array_combine($measurement_id, $measurements);

        $syncData = array();
        foreach($result as $measurement_id=> $filteredmeasurements){
            $syncData[$measurement_id] = array('measurement' => $filteredmeasurements);
        }

        $customer->measurementparts()->sync($syncData);
        return redirect()->route('customers.index')->withStatus(__('Measurements successfully Updated.'));

    }
```

View EditMeasurements.blade.php

```
<form action="{{ route('updateMeasurements', ['customer'=> $customer]) }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @foreach ($clothType as $item)
        <tr>
            <h3>{{ $item->name }}</h3>
            <table>
                @foreach ($item->measurementparts as $part)
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img style="width: 191px;" class="img"
                                src="{{ asset('storage/image/' . $part->image) }}" alt="">
                                <input type="hidden" name="measurement_id[]" value="{{$part->id}}">
                        </td>
                        <td><a href="">{{ $part->name }}</a></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="measurement[]" value="**I want to put here my measurment value**" class="form-control"></td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            </table>
        </tr>
        <br>
        <hr>
    @endforeach
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

this is the image where I want to put
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baoGJ.png)

Comment: Could you please show all `CustomerMeasurement` model?

Comment: All code are there please check CustomerMeasurement.php